# How to create a dll when building a solution

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, dll, sqlclr

I am practicing CLR function in SQL Server:
C# => dll => assembly => CLR function

I have a solution that works fine as a Console App,
but after I execute "Build Solution" I don't find a dll file in ..\MyProj\MyProj\obj\Debug\ as expected.
In other solution I do find it and it works fine.
I guess I miss something in the definitions or the properties of solution.

Can you kindly guide me what to do/change/find/check?

Comment: Try ..\MyProj\MyProj\bin\Debug\

Comment: Console application does not produce a dll file. It produces only executable file. Further if you will create a library/project the dll file will be in bin folder of your project.

Answer (score 5):

The output of your project depends on your project type. A project type console application produces an exe file. What you need is a project of type class library.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a SQL Server Database Project as it will tie into SSDT which will handle the publishing for you.

You should also be aware that what you created as a Console App might not work within SQL Server's CLR host (i.e. SQLCLR). SQLCLR is a highly restricted .NET environment and there are quite a few nuances to it, such as only really having the following subset of libraries available to you: [Supported .NET Framework Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/database-objects/supported-net-framework-libraries).

For more information on working with SQLCLR in general, please see the series of articles I am writing on this topic on SQL Server Central (free registration is required to read content on that site): [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/).